# How to Click an Icon using VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation, queryselector

I am not new to VBA but I am new to coding anything that interacts with the web. I can open the web page which then has several icons. I need help on clicking a specific icon.
Here is the HTML that appears when I right click the desired icon and click "Inspect element":

```
<div title="" class="myapps-myapp resource" position="N" index="22">
    <div class="myapps-icon-background"></div>
    <a class="myapps-icon" href="#">
    <img class="iconImage" alt="SomeName"
        src="Resources/Icon/aklhdjQ2QWJGVVQxcHpUcEJ5RG5FcEZwcytzPQ--
?size=48"
        iconid="akltdjStWJGVVRxcHpUcEJ7QG3FcEZwtytzMT">
    </a>
    <div class="myapps-status"></div>
    <div class="myapps-name">SomeName</div>
    </div>
```

Here is my VBA code that I have so far:

```
Sub test()
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim oBrowser As Internet Explorer
Dim objIE As Variant
Set objIE = Create Object("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.navigate "http://The webpage goes here" 'This open the site       
While objIE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE And objIE.readyState & _
    <> READYSTATE_LOADED
    DoEvents
Wend
For Each oHTML_Element In objIE.document.getElementsByName & _
("SomeName")
    oHTML_Element.Click   'This does not work!
Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the value of the `alt` attribute you want to match on. No loop.

```
objIe.document.querySelector("[alt='RevenueCycle P0657 YAVA_AZ']").click
```

Though it may actually be the `a` tag you want to click

```
objIe.document.querySelector("[index='22'] .myapps-icon").click
```

Read about:

1. [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
2. [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)